# Use Google APIs to calculate the timezones of each location object and then return output as this same array of objects

Tags: json, google-api

1) a) You have a list of addresses. Use Google APIs to calculate the timezones of each location object and then return output as this same array of objects, with each object comprising of following values -

```
[{ 
 "id":"1",
"address":"Plot 5, CDCL Building, Chandigarh"m
"latitude":"30.123123",
"longitude":"76.123213"
"timezone":"-330", //in minutes 
"UTC_time":"2016-10-18 5:30:00 AM"
}]
```

b) Now write an algorithm, to divide this array into least no. of sub-arrays, such that difference between the minimum UTC_time and maximum UTC_time in that array is less than or equal to 4 hrs.

2) Parse the attached html file and generate a JSON file as output, which contains all the key

**FORMAT**

```
Test Duration- 5 Hours 
Test Date -27 October,2016
Format to be send in :  "Student name- college name -roll number- 2016"|| 
Email Id - kunal@tookanapp.com  ( All the students need to send their test on the mentioned email ID in the mentioned format ) 
Start Time - 11.00 AM 
End Time - 4.00 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go through this link.You will get the answer.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm not a program::--

initialise i, ar [100],d ;

MAX UTC_time= +14:00(150°);

Min UTC_time=-12:00 (180°);

for min UTC_time initialise to -12:00;

min UTC_time <=+14:00

If  min UTC_time > +10:00

Then d=max UTC _time - min UTC_time;

And then print d;

Else

Min UTC_time++;

Link is :--

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&timestamp=1331766000&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

{
   "dstOffset" : 0,

"rawOffset" : -28800,

"status" : "OK",

"timeZoneId" : "America/Los_Angeles",

"timeZoneName" : "Pacific Standard Time"
}

Answer (score 0):

In html language......

OK

-28800.0000000

0.0000000

America/Los_Angeles

Pacific Standard Time

time_zone_name>